# Bootable USB not working for me

Tags: boot, usb

I currently have an HP computer that is only a few months old. The computer recently started running super slow and I was going to change from Windows 7 to Ubuntu as I know that Windows has way more viruses available than Ubuntu.

I used the *Pendrivelinux* software to change the ISO to USB and it said complete. I then took the USB, plugged it into my computer and at the screen that pops up before the Windows logo I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>. The only thing I could choose was Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: You are already in the windows boot manager on this screen. 
The initial boot screen (BIOS messages) will tell you which keys to press for Setup or Boot menu. Choose either one and select to boot from USB first. The moment you see any Windows message, it means you've waited too long to press F2, F10, F11, F12 or whatever key brings you to the Setup or Boot menu

Answer (score 5):

Try using f10 instead of f12, there will be advanced options for your computer, in the advanced pane, you can change the boot order, or you can also sometimes press esc to change the boot order.

***Some computer start-up procedures are different so f10 may not work, that is why I listed the other possibilities.***

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the **BIOS** setup and `change your boot device order`. Change your boot order so that PC boots from USB first. Then try using the **LIVE USB.**